# how to dynamically import a react component and call it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a react component that contains an SVG image.
and i import it like this

`import MessageIcon from '../static/styles/svg/messageIcon';`

However as part of code splitting, i want to dynamically import it instead of static import.

I tried like this but does not work

`import('../static/styles/svg/messageIcon').then(MessageIcon => { return <MessageIcon /> });`

can anyone tell me how i can dynamically import and call this component? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can import dynamical like this :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<any>();

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const i = await import("../../assets/img/user.svg");
            setState(i);
        })();
    }, []);
    
    return <img alt={"test dynamic"} src={state?.default} />;
};
export default App;
```

Also, you can write it with `ref` too:

```js
    import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

    const App = () => {
        const ref = useRef<any>();

        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const i = await import("../../assets/img/user.svg");
                ref.current.src = i.default;
            })();
        }, []);
        
        return <img alt={"test dynamic"} ref={ref} />;
    };
    export default App;
```

**import dynamical React component**

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
      const nameIcon = "iconMessage";
      const IconMessage = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "icon" */ `./${nameIcon}`));

      return <IconMessage />;
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks ijavad for the reply. I understood your solution. But in my case, the SVG itself a react component.



`import MessageIcon from '../static/styles/svg/messageIcon';`

the above 'MessageIcon' is a react component which I need to dynamically import and  call

Comment: oh sorry dude it is my mistake I didn't see it a component react, so you can use React lazy, I will update this Awnser